# C# Interfaces with static methods

Tags: c#

This is my Interface:

```
interface IComandos<T>
{
    void Inserir();
    IList<T> Pesquisar(string termo);
    void Editar();
    void Excluir();
}
```

Here, a class implementing the Interface:

```
 class Partido : IComandos<Partido>
        {
            public string Nome { get; set; }
            public string Sigla { get; set; }
        ...

    public IList<Partido> Pesquisar(string termo)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Question: I need my "Pesquisar" method to be **static**. How can I do it? I really need my Method to work like this -> *Partido.Pesquisar("something");*

Comment: _"I need my "Pesquisar" method to be static"_ Why (do you think that) ?

Comment: Well if you really need a static method, define a static method. What is the problem? *Partido* is a class and you can define static methods for a class

Answer (score -1):

From MSDN [Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156(v=vs.100).aspx):

> An interface cannot contain constants, fields, operators, instance
>   constructors, destructors, or types. **It cannot contain static members.**
>   Interfaces members are automatically public, and they cannot include
>   any access modifiers.

So the answer is: no, you cannot define static member in interface.

Comment: Starting with C# 8.0 you can have static methods and fields in interfaces.